# Kendo UI kendoTreeList ExportToExcel : "Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined", with aggregate columns

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, dojo, export-to-excel, kendo-treeview

I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined" when aggregate column use with KendoTreeList and try to export to excel.
I get same error for sum and max aggregate.

```
<div id="treelist"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var service = "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service";

            $("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
                toolbar: [ "excel" ],
                excel: {
                    fileName: "Kendo UI TreeList Export.xlsx",
                    proxyURL: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export",
                    filterable: true
                },
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: service + "/EmployeeDirectory/All",
                            dataType: "jsonp"
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "EmployeeId",
                            parentId: "ReportsTo",
                            fields: {
                                ReportsTo: { nullable: true },
                                EmployeeId: {  type: "number" },
                                HireDate: { field: "HireDate", type: "date" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    aggregate: [
                        { field: "FirstName", aggregate: "count" },
                        { field: "HireDate", aggregate: "max" }
                    ]
                },
                height: 540,
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                columns: [
                    { field: "FirstName", title: "Name",
                      template: "#: FirstName # #: LastName #",
                      footerTemplate: "#= count # employee(s)" },
                    { field: "Position" },
                    { field: "HireDate", title: "Hire Date", format: "{0:MMMM d, yyyy}",
                      footerTemplate: "Last employee hired on #= kendo.format('{0:MMMM d, yyyy}', max) #" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I also try with this demo code [Kendo UI Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oGuje), but no success.

Is anyone have same issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is caused by a change in scope.

When the grid is created, `#= count #` really is referring to `#= data.FirstName.count #`. Now in grid creation, `data` is being interpreted as a single data row, and so `data.Firstname.Count` is defined. However, on ExportToExcel `data` is not a row of data, it is an array of all data elements in your grid.

So `#= data.FirstName.count #` does not work.

There are two ways to solve this issue. The first (and best way) you could do it is to rewrite your model to use groups instead of this parent/child relationship you have implemented. If you do this you can access the group aggregates in both events with `#=data.aggregates.FirstName.count#`.

Second, you could use a custom aggregate function and only use it on export. Something like:

```
footerTemplate: (data: any) => {
    var rVal = 0
    if (data.count) { // If count is defined, this is just a data row so just use count. 
        rval = data.count;
    } else {  // Otherwise use the custom function.
        data.forEach((item: any, index: any) => { // For each item, if it has a count, count it.  
            rVal = (item.FirstName) ? (rVal + item.FirstName.Count) : rVal;
        });
    }                       
    return `${rVal} employee(s)`; \\ The final sum is the grand total. 
}
```

custom aggregates don't work in the dojo example as they are not officially supported by Telerik, but I was able to get it working locally. This works, but I would really recommend the first option.

Just a note, if you ever lose track of what `data` refers to you can use `#=console.log(data)#` to see what it looks like in each context/event.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Somehow when you export to Excel, Kendo doesn't provide the `count` and `max` to the `footerTemplate`. So we'll have to provide the `count` and `max` when they are not defined. Try the code below in the Telerik DOJO. The workaround is to assign the TreeList object to a reference so that we can get the `dataSource`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/aggregates">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.4.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
        <div id="treelist"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var service = "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service";

                var treeList = $("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
                    toolbar: [ "excel" ],
                    excel: {
                        fileName: "Kendo UI TreeList Export.xlsx",
                    },
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: service + "/EmployeeDirectory/All",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            }
                        },
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "EmployeeId",
                                parentId: "ReportsTo",
                                fields: {
                                    ReportsTo: { nullable: true },
                                    EmployeeId: {  type: "number" },
                                    HireDate: { field: "HireDate", type: "date" }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        aggregate: [
                            { field: "FirstName", aggregate: "count" },
                            { field: "HireDate", aggregate: "max" }
                        ]
                    },
                    height: 540,
                    filterable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    columns: [
                        { 
                          field: "FirstName", 
                          title: "Name",
                          template: "#: FirstName # #: LastName #",
                          footerTemplate: function(dataItem) {
                            if (dataItem.count) {
                              return dataItem.count + ' employee(s)';
                            } else {
                              var ds = treeList.dataSource;
                              return ds._aggregateResult.null.FirstName.count + ' employee(s)';
                            }
                          },
                        },
                        { 
                          field: "Position" 
                        },
                        { 
                          field: "HireDate", 
                          title: "Hire Date", 
                          format: "{0:MMMM d, yyyy}",
                          footerTemplate: function(dataItem) {
                            if (dataItem.max) {
                                return 'Last employee hired on ' + kendo.format('{0:MMMM d, yyyy}', dataItem.max);
                            } else {
                              var ds = treeList.dataSource;
                              return 'Last employee hired on ' + kendo.format('{0:MMMM d, yyyy}', 
                                ds._aggregateResult.null.HireDate.max);
                            }
                          },
                        }
                    ]
                }).data('kendoTreeList');
            });
        </script>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```